# How to build a child model from doubled model in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In a model spec I had a succeed test like this:

```
let(:parent){ Parent.new(foo: nil) }
let(:child){ parent.build_child(bar: 100) }
it 'is nil' do
    expect(parent.hoge(child)).to eq(nil)
end
```

I changed the `foo` from a column to a method of `Parent`.

So I have to create a double, what I wrote was:

```
let(:parent){ double 'parent', foo: nil }
```

And got a message like this:

```
Double "parent" received unexpected message :build_child with ({:bar=>100})
```

Probably I'm doing something completely wrong, how can I write a test in this case?

Comment: that test is weird. Anyway if you want to set expectations on a double try `expect(parent).to receive(:build_child).with(bar: 100)`

Comment: you would put that before calling `child`, i.e. before your first expectation